# Hide PageFooter on Fastreport

Tags: fastreport

I have a pagefooter where I hide it after the 1st page with a script, but as you can see in the photo it seems to be taking up space, can I do something about it?

Version 6.4

```
function PageHeader1OnBeforePrint(Sender)
{
   if (<Page#> < 2 )

    {Sender.Visible = True;} 

    else {Sender.Visible = False;}
}

function PageFooter1OnBeforePrint(Sender)

{           
   if (<Page#> < 2 )

    {Sender.Visible = True; }

    else {Sender.Visible = False;                  

    }       
}
```

[image]